# Calculating many distances between cities

Tags: android

Is it feasible ( i mean from time point of view ) for an activity to calculate multiple distances between cities given that is a lot of work or the user has to wait for minutes; We talk about atleast 20 distances to be calculate every time...

Comment: Why not use a Thread?

Comment: yes, it is feasible,

Comment: The best approach is to create an AsyncTask that receives a List of cities. You can perform the math inside there while you show a progress bar to the user.